# cURL 400 badly formed request

Tags: php, curl

Windows NT DEV01 6.2 build 9200 (Unknown Windows version Standard Edition) i586
PHP Version 5.4.24
allow_url_fopen = On

The url I'm using looks like this:

```
http://www.warrantycompany.com/services/rate.asmx/GetRates?AccountNumber=37920N&DRFC=0&Mileage=52000&VIN=1G2ZA5EK3A4163364&ManufacturerWarranty=y&BrandedOrSalvaged=branded&EngineCC=0
```

And the relevant PHP code looks like this:

```
$curlSession = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT , 30);

curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

$sTemp = curl_exec($curlSession);

echo curl_errno($curlSession);
echo curl_error($curlSession);
```

Loaded into a browser directly, I get a long block of XML with the information I want. Through cURL, however, I get "HTTP Error 400. The request is badly formed."

If I change the URL to read

```
http://www.warrantycompany.com/services/rate.asmx/GetRates/?AccountNumber=...
```

(note the forward slash before the question mark) I get the same.

If I change the URL to

```
http://www.warrantycompany.com/services/rate.asmx/GetRates?AccountNumber%3D37920N%26DRFC%3D0%26...
```

using urlencode() on the parameters, the request works, but the remote system errors out.

file_get_contents returns "false".

The only way this works - and has worked to date - is to use the server object "MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP", which I'd like to not if possible, but I'm at a loss.

Comment: When I copy the URL in to a browser, I get an error message and a 404. Probably you should first check what the server app exactly is accepting before trying to fiddle with unknown parameters etc. This looks like an API and there should be some kind of documentation.

Comment: Yes, you're getting a 404 error: the url in my example uses a fake domain since this is code for my job. As I say in the text, loaded into a browser directly, the url I'm using (the actual URL) works just fine; I get XML back with the desired information.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
//put your parameters in a array with key/value like this
$arr = array('AccountNumber' => 37920, 'DRFC' => 0,......); 

//set the base url of the service  
$url = 'http://www.warrantycompany.com/services/rate.asmx';

$uri = http_build_query($arr, '', '&');
$uri = str_replace (array('+',' '), '%20', $uri);
$url = sprintf("%s?%s", $url, $uri);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT , 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$sTemp = curl_exec($ch);

echo curl_errno($ch);
echo curl_error($ch);
curl_close ($ch);


//you can handle the respond like this
list($header, $body) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $respond, 2);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the example omits a key part of the URL, and in any case, yes, I've tried it with encoding, as you can see in the original description.